# UItableView last rows are not displayed well

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have 3 class who are the `ShopViewController`, `ShopCellClass` and the `ShopClass`

I build my shop programmatically and I want to insert a gradient with two colors given by the ShopClass. The problem is the last gradient don't have the good color.. I show you the code of my 3 classes :

`ShopViewController` :

```
class ShopViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(ShopCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellShop")
        tableView.rowHeight = 155
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return shop.data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"CellShop") as! ShopCellClass
        cell.drawTheCard(index: indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
}
```

my `ShopCellClass` :

```
class ShopCellClass : UITableViewCell {

    var widthOfCard : CGFloat = 0
    var heightOfCard : CGFloat = 0

    let cardView = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.contentView.addSubview(cardView)
        widthOfCard = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        heightOfCard = 155
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func drawTheCard(index : Int){
        drawCard(index: index)
    }

    private func drawCard(index: Int){
        cardView.frame = CGRect(x : 0, y : 0, width : widthOfCard, height : heightOfCard)

        let gradientBg = UIView()
        gradientBg.frame = cardView.bounds

        let leftColor = shop.data[index].leftColor
        let rightColor = shop.data[index].rightColor

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [leftColor.cgColor,
                                rightColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect.init(
            x: cardView.bounds.origin.x,
            y: cardView.bounds.origin.y,
            width: widthOfCard,
            height: heightOfCard)
        gradientLayer.masksToBounds = false

        cardView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

and my `ShopClass` :

```
class ShopClass {
    var data: [(id : Int, name : String, price : Double, leftColor : UIColor, rightColor : UIColor)] = []

    init(){
        self.loadShopData()
    }

    func loadShopData(){
        data.append((id : 1, name : "Pack 1", price : 4.99, leftColor : UIColor(rgb: 0xA46628), rightColor : UIColor(rgb: 0xE08B37))) // Brown
        data.append((id : 2, name : "Pack 2", price : 9.99, leftColor : UIColor(rgb: 0x8C8C8C), rightColor : UIColor(rgb: 0xAFAFAF))) // Gray
        data.append((id : 3, name : "Pack 3", price : 15.99, leftColor : UIColor(rgb: 0xF3B700), rightColor : UIColor(rgb: 0xF3CD00))) // Yellow
        data.append((id : 4, name : "Pack 4", price : 19.99, leftColor : UIColor(rgb: 0x980000), rightColor : UIColor(rgb: 0xF20000))) // Red
        data.append((id : 5, name : "Pack 5", price : 24.99, leftColor : UIColor(rgb : 0x000000), rightColor : UIColor(rgb : 0x2C2C2C))) // Black
    }
}

let shop = ShopClass()
```

Normally, defined by the `ShopClass` the colors of the gradient are:

-> Brown -> Gray -> Yellow -> Red -> Black

but I have :

-> Brown -> Gray -> Yellow -> Black // WRONG -> Brown // WRONG

like show the gif :

[image]

So my question is why are my two last colors wrong ?

The error show in the iPhone 8 simulator, not the iPhone X. Maybe a problem of the rowHeight ?

Comment: what is this: `let leftColor = shop.data[index].leftColor`? what is that: `let rightColor = shop.data[index].rightColor`? what is `shop` in this encapsulation?

Comment: I don't know about your colors but you have size issue. You should implement the UITableViewDelegate method heightForRowAt and define rowHeight.

Comment: @holex this is the colors give in the `ShopClass` and get by this : `let shop = ShopClass()`

Comment: @Balanced I already fix the height to the row at 155 here `tableView.rowHeight = 155` and when I add the delegate `heightForRowAt` nothing happening...

Comment: implement prepareForReuse method of UITableViewCell and clear/reset color there and then let the tableview reuse it.

Comment: and what is the connection between `ShopCellClass` and `ShopClass`...?

Comment: @holex `let shop = ShopClass()` this declared ShopClass as "global class" let can I use in all my project as I want.

Comment: @vivekDas Thanks it's work very well. Can you explain why?

Comment: @El-Burritosc the problem was with the reusing cells, so you should use prepareForReuse method whenever you think it required to reset things.

Comment: @vivekDas Thanks